# How to grant rights properly to a folder on IIS 7.5 Express

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-authentication, application-pool

I'm getting a quite common exception: `Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Content\Images\Uploads\<there goes my hashed guid as a subfolder name which is created dynamically>'`

I'm using `IIS Express 7.5`. I'm using `WA` authentication in my application. Impersonation's disabled both in `web.config` and on `IIS`.

I looked at application pool the site is running (which is `ASP.NET 4.0`). Application pool identity: `Network Service`. I have given full control rights to the `Uploads` folder for `IIS AppPool\ASP.NET 4.0`. Also did this for *authenticated users*. Checked I did this for subfolders.

**EDIT**

Helped a little http://forums.asp.net/t/984207.aspx/1

I have created the folder: `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Content\Images\Uploads`. It wasn't present on my `C` drive before). Then I added full control permissions for `Network Authority` on the folder and successfully uploaded a file to the path.

So I'm just curious where should I keep my project folder? Now I keeping it on other drive, not `C`.

**EDIT**

Ok. I understood. All this is connected to my code where `Server.MapPath` is called.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the identity for application pool ASP.NET 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must give permission to the **Uploads** folder for `NetworkService` witch is the `ASP.NET 4.0` identity.

Comment: I use `Network Service` identity because when switched to `ApplicationPoolIdentity` it thows exception on accessing a database requested by login (`ASP.NET 4.0`).

Comment: I don't know for sure: see when I assigned permissions (`FullControl`) to the folder I checked that it's applied to all files/subfolders, but subfolders created dynamically and their names are based on some hashed database records. Who knows maybe that's the culprit?

Comment: by default sub folder will inherits permissions from parent. I think when you get error your sub folder must be exist, you can check then.